# Remove copyright year from cakephp

Tags: cakephp

I am trying to remove ©2016  from the bottom of each page in cakephp , And I can't find it

I am using a different default template `TwitterBootstrap` , I was able to find it in the new template and comment it out, But It is not gone no matter if I used the default template or the new one

I can't find it anywhere , I tried searching for  `&copy;` and `date('Y')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have DebugKit enabled, rendered templates should show up in the "Timer" tab. (BTW, did you just search for a literal `©` character.)

Comment: thanks, When I saw the rendered templates in the "Timer" tab, I found another template in the "vendor/friendsofcake" plugin directory which contained what I was looking for, At first I excluded that directory to search faster